# What are some efficient ways to combine two structures in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, merge, structure, field

I want to combine two structures with differing fields names.

For example, starting with:

```
A.field1 = 1;
A.field2 = 'a';

B.field3 = 2;
B.field4 = 'b';
```

I would like to have:

```
C.field1 = 1;
C.field2 = 'a';
C.field3 = 2;
C.field4 = 'b';
```

Is there a more efficient way than using "fieldnames" and a for loop?

**EDIT:** Let's assume that in the case of field name conflicts we give preference to `A`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without collisions, you can do

```
M = [fieldnames(A)' fieldnames(B)'; struct2cell(A)' struct2cell(B)'];
C=struct(M{:});
```

And this is reasonably efficient. However, `struct` errors on duplicate fieldnames, and pre-checking for them using `unique` kills performance to the point that a loop is better. But here's what it would look like:

```
M = [fieldnames(A)' fieldnames(B)'; struct2cell(A)' struct2cell(B)'];

[tmp, rows] = unique(M(1,:), 'last');
M=M(:, rows);

C=struct(M{:});
```

You might be able to make a hybrid solution by assuming no conflicts and using a try/catch around the call to `struct` to gracefully degrade to the conflict handling case.

Comment: The first solution could be transformed into a one liner by `cell2struct`. I don't know about the performance of it though.

Answer (score 10):

Short answer: **`setstructfields`** (if you have the Signal Processing Toolbox).

---

The official solution is posted by Loren Shure on [her MathWorks blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/15/concatenating-structs/), and demonstrated by [SCFrench here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39678/2778484) and in [Eitan T's answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15257983/2778484).  However, if you have the Signal Processing Toolbox, a simple undocumented function does this already - `setstructfields`.

**`help setstructfields`**

```
 setstructfields Set fields of a structure using another structure
    setstructfields(STRUCTIN, NEWFIELDS) Set fields of STRUCTIN using
    another structure NEWFIELDS fields.  If fields exist in STRUCTIN
    but not in NEWFIELDS, they will not be changed.
```

Internally it uses `fieldnames` and a `for` loop, so it is a convenience function with error checking and recursion for fields that are themselves structs.

**Example**

The "original" struct:

```
% struct with fields 'color' and 'count'
s = struct('color','orange','count',2)

s = 
    color: 'orange'
    count: 2
```

A second struct containing a new value for `'count'`, and a new field, `'shape'`:

```
% struct with fields 'count' and 'shape'
s2 = struct('count',4,'shape','round')

s2 = 
    count: 4
    shape: 'round'
```

Calling `setstructfields`:

```
>> s = setstructfields(s,s2)
s = 
    color: 'orange'
    count: 4
    shape: 'round'
```

The field `'count'` is *updated*.  The field `'shape'` is *added*. The field `'color'` *remains unchanged*.

**NOTE**: Since the function is undocumented, it may change or be removed at any time.

Answer (score 5):

I have found a nice [solution on File Exchange: catstruct](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7842-catstruct).

Without testing the performance I can say that it did exactly what I wanted.
It can deal with duplicate fields of course.

Here is how it works:

```
a.f1 = 1;
a.f2 = 2;
b.f2 = 3;
b.f4 = 4;

s = catstruct(a,b)
```

Will give

```
s = 

    f1: 1
    f2: 3
    f3: 4
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can handle conflicts well w/o a loop, nor do I think you'd need to avoid one. (although I suppose efficiency could be an issue w/ many many fields...)

I use a function I wrote a few years back called `setdefaults.m`, which combines one structure with the values of another structure, where one takes precedence over the other in case of conflict.

```
% SETDEFAULTS sets the default structure values 
%    SOUT = SETDEFAULTS(S, SDEF) reproduces in S 
%    all the structure fields, and their values,  that exist in 
%    SDEF that do not exist in S. 
%    SOUT = SETDEFAULTS(S, SDEF, OVERRIDE) does
%    the same function as above, but if OVERRIDE is 1,
%    it copies all fields of SDEF to SOUT.

function sout = setdefaults(s,sdef,override)
if (not(exist('override','var')))
    override = 0;
end

sout = s;
for f = fieldnames(sdef)'
    cf = char(f);
    if (override | not(isfield(sout,cf)))
        sout = setfield(sout,cf,getfield(sdef,cf));
    end
end
```

Now that I think about it, I'm pretty sure that the "override" input is unnecessary (you can just switch the order of the inputs) though I'm not 100% sure of that... so here's a simpler rewrite (`setdefaults2.m`):

```
% SETDEFAULTS2 sets the default structure values 
%    SOUT = SETDEFAULTS(S, SDEF) reproduces in S 
%    all the structure fields, and their values,  that exist in 
%    SDEF that do not exist in S. 

function sout = setdefaults2(s,sdef)
sout = sdef;
for f = fieldnames(s)'
    sout = setfield(sout,f{1},getfield(s,f{1}));
end
```

and some samples to test it:

```
>> S1 = struct('a',1,'b',2,'c',3);
>> S2 = struct('b',4,'c',5,'d',6);
>> setdefaults2(S1,S2)

ans = 

    b: 2
    c: 3
    d: 6
    a: 1

>> setdefaults2(S2,S1)

ans = 

    a: 1
    b: 4
    c: 5
    d: 6
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the behaviour I need. I wonder why it is not a part of the standard library.

Comment: As of MATLAB 6.5 (Release 13), dynamic field references may be used to simplify the statement inside the loop: `sout.(f{1}) = s.(f{1});`

Answer (score 2):

In C, a struct can have another struct as one of it's members.  While this isn't exactly the same as what you're asking, you could end up either with a situation where one struct contains another, or one struct contains two structs, both of which hold parts of the info that you wanted.

psuedocode: i don't remember the actual syntax.

```
A.field1 = 1;
A.field2 = 'a';
A.field3 = struct B;
```

to access:
    A.field3.field4;

or something of the sort.

Or you could have struct C hold both an A and a B:

```
C.A = struct A;
C.B = struct B;
```

with access then something like

```
C.A.field1;
C.A.field2;
C.B.field3;
C.B.field4;
```

hope this helps!

EDIT: both of these solutions avoid naming collisions.

Also, I didn't see your `matlab` tag.  By convention, you should want to edit the question to include that piece of info.