# update struct via another struct in Matlab

Tags: matlab, struct

I'm wondering if there is a convenient way to **update a struct** with the values of  another struct in Matlab.
Here is the code, with the use of `fieldnames`, `numel` and a `for` loop,

```
fn = fieldnames(new_values);
for fi=1:numel(fn)
    old_struct.(fn{fi}) = new_values.(fn{fi});
end
```

Of course, I don't want to loose the fields in `old_struct` that are not in `new_values`, so I can't use the simple `old_struct=new_values`.

Updating a struct is something we may want to do in a single short line in an interpreter.

Comment: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/15/concatenating-structs/

Comment: Theses answers are either not relevant (assuming no collision) or use the same `for` loop + `fieldnames` method. This tends to confirm the fact that there is no simpler way, but does not give a clean evidence ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are convinced that there is no simpler way to achieve what you want, here is the method described in [Loren Shure's article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/15/concatenating-structs/) (see link posted in Dan's comment), applied to your example:

```
%// Remove overlapping fields from first struct
s_merged = rmfield(s_old, intersect(fieldnames(s_old), fieldnames(s_new)));

%// Obtain all unique names of remaining fields
names = [fieldnames(s_merged); fieldnames(s_new)];

%// Merge both structs
s_merged = cell2struct([struct2cell(s_merged); struct2cell(s_new)], names, 1);
```

Note that this slightly improved version can handle arrays of structs, as well as structs with overlapping field names (this is what I believe you call *collision*).

Comment: Would this still work if one of the fields is also a struct?

Comment: @Leo I believe so, but the best approach in this case is to try it and see! :-)