# How to simply concatenate two structures with different fields in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, struct

Is there any simple way to combine the following two structures, without using for loop or CELLFUN?

```
struct1 = 

    a: {43x1 cell}

struct2 = 

    b: [43x1 double]
    c: {43x1 cell}
```

I would like to have the combined structure like this:

```
struct3 = 

    a: {43x1 cell}
    b: [43x1 double]
    c: {43x1 cell}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [update struct via another struct in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245167/update-struct-via-another-struct-in-matlab) and [What are some efficient ways to combine two structures in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645/what-are-some-efficient-ways-to-combine-two-structures-in-matlab).

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer in [update struct via another struct in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245167/update-struct-via-another-struct-in-matlab)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got what I want by using the suggestion in [update struct via another struct in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245167/update-struct-via-another-struct-in-matlab), as follows:

```
names = [fieldnames(struct1); fieldnames(struct2)];
struct3 = cell2struct([struct2cell(struct1); struct2cell(struct2)], names, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider [this article and associated MATLAB Exchange script](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-172VF/index.html?product=SL&solution=1-172VF) from Mathworks:

> **Subject**:
>
> How can I concatenate or merge two structures? Problem Description:
>
> I would like to merge two structures into a new structure containing
>   all the fields of the two original structures. How can I do this in
>   MATLAB?
>
> **Solution**:
>
> There is no direct ability in MATLAB that can be used to concatenate
>   structures.
>
> The attached file mergeStructs.m shows a number of methods that can be
>   used to merge structures in MATLAB.
>
> There are also online submissions on the MATLAB Central User Community
>   that you can use. One such submission is :
>
> http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7842
>
> Note that MathWorks does not guarantee or warrant the use or content
>   of these submissions. Any questions, issues, or complaints should be
>   directed to the contributing author.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this article, but it uses for loop to have the concatenation.