# How to add new element to structure array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

How to add new element to structure array? I am unable to concatenate with empty structure:

```
>> a=struct;
>> a.f1='hi'

a = 

    f1: 'hi'

>> a.f2='bye'

a = 

    f1: 'hi'
    f2: 'bye'

>> a=cat(1,a,struct)
Error using cat
Number of fields in structure arrays being concatenated do not match. Concatenation of structure arrays requires that these arrays have the same set of
fields.
```

So is it possible to add new element with empty fields?

**UPDATE**

I found that I can add new element if I simultaneously add new field:

```
>> a=struct()

a = 

struct with no fields.

>> a.f1='hi';
>> a.f2='bye';
>> a(end+1).iamexist=true

a = 

1x2 struct array with fields:

    f1
    f2
    iamexist
```

It is incredible that there is no straight way! May be there is some colon equivalent for structures?

Comment: You could do something like this: `a(n) = a(1)`

Answer (score 5):

If you're lazy to type out the fields again or if there are too many then here is a short cut to get a struct of empty fields

```
a.f1='hi'
a.f2='bye'

%assuming there is not yet a variable called EmptyStruct
EmptyStruct(2) = a;
EmptyStruct = EmptyStruct(1);
```

now `EmptyStruct` is the empty struct you desire. So to add new ones

```
a(2) = EmptyStruct; %or cat(1, a, EmptyStruct) or [a, EmptyStruct] etc...



a(2)

ans = 

    f1: []
    f2: []
```

Answer (score 3):

You can only concatenate structures with identical fields.

Let's denote your second struct by `b`. As you have already checked, the following won't work, because struct `a` has two fields and `b` has none:

```
a = struct('f1', 'hi', 'f2', 'bye');
b = struct;
[a; b]
```

However, this works:

```
a = struct('f1', 'hi', 'f2', 'bye');
b = struct('f1', [], 'f2', []);
[a; b]
```

If you want to "automatically" create an empty structure with the same fields as `a` (without having to type all of them), you can either use [Dan's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17805633/1336150) or do this:

```
a = struct('f1', 'hi', 'f2', 'bye');

C = reshape(fieldnames(a), 1, []); %// Field names
C(2, :) = {[]};                    %// Empty values
b = struct(C{:});

[a; b]
```

I also recommend reading the following:

1. [Stack Overflow - What are some efficient ways to combine two structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645/what-are-some-efficient-ways-to-combine-two-structures-in-matlab)
2. [Stack Overflow - Update struct via another struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245167/update-struct-via-another-struct-in-matlab)
3. [Loren on the Art of MATLAB - Concatenating structs](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/15/concatenating-structs/)